# how to split first line in listbox and copy it into webbrowser1 elemnt in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, split

c# split first line in listbox1 and copy the one before "|" then paste it into webbrowser1 element  and the second,  third

elements in listbox1 like this :
1111111|88|8888|888|

first step 
copy  1111111
then past it into getElemtby id past it into this id input

second step
copy the 2nd 88
if it is equal put it in webbrowser1 element by id like month 01 to 12

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("month").SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "1");
```

third step
copy the third 8888
if it is equal put it in webbrowser1 element by id like month 2018 to 2029

if it like 2018 to put

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("year").SetAttribute("selectedIndex", "1");
```

third step copy the four 888
and paste it in id in webbrowser1

doing these steps line by line till end of length listbox1

then
click on element 
I tried this one below

```
workwebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ys_primary").InvokeMember("click");
```

then 
check if the next page in webbrowser1 and deal with it like copy any item id

Comment: M khaled: FYI the `visual-studio` tag is for questions related to the Visual Studio editor. I've removed it from your question for you.

Comment: Are you expecting someone to write the code for you, or are you just looking for hints on how to solve some of the problems?

Comment: just need hints on how to solve some of the problems
you see i know but not there some need

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear but i think you just need string.Split.

```
var parts = listbox1.SelectedItem.Text.Split('|');
```

This will give you an array of strings, that you need to put into your existing code (Selenium?)

Comment: i need it for the first line in listbox
 listBox1.Items[0].ToString() 

44444444444|09|2018|555|
copy 44444444444
then 09
then 2018
then 555
to past it in webbrowser1

Answer (score 0):

```
    // here is the solution 
        string str = listBox1.Items[0].ToString();

        char[] b = new char[str.Length];

   using (StringReader sr = new StringReader(str))
        {
            // Read 16 characters from the string into the array.
            sr.Read(b, 0, 16);

    //  to show the result print
            string output = string.Join("", b);
            MessageBox.Show(output);

    //  but what if i want to read from 5 to 9
    // it does not resolve yet!
```

Comment: StackOverflow is  a Q&A site not a forum. The Answers section is not actual answers to the question, not clarifications or alterations of the question. Please **edit your question** to include this update.